# Adapt website for blind people

Tags: html, audio, accessibility

As my title explains, how do I adapt a website for blind people? From what I've heard, there's a new Swedish law at the end of this year that says that websites should be adapted for blind people. It doesn't concern all websites, but website that contain information about the authorities such as police, hospitals, banks, pension/retirement benefit and so on.

This is the absolute first time I've heard of this. I have no idea how to adapt the homepage for blind people for the company I work for. Any ideas?

Where do I begin and how do I apply sounds that reads the content of the site? Is there any tutorial on this matter?

Comment: If your company needs to support accessibility, I recommend installing a screen reader that would be used by the blind.  This would be really useful for testing purposes.  Aside from that, you'll go a long way toward accessibility by effectively separating content/style/functionality (screen readers focus on content), structuring the content semantically, and ensuring that style/functionality aren't *required* in order to use the site.  (It should be usable with JavaScript turned off, should look structured with CSS turned off, etc.)

Comment: This is for the U.S., but it may have some valuable information for you:  http://webaim.org/standards/508/checklist

Comment: This topic is far too broad for single question at SO. You should first check what the law actually says. Blind people are a small fraction of visually impaired people, which are small fraction of people to whom accessibility is crucial. You should also care about the *actual* accessibility, as opposite to what the law might require. You are *not* expected to create a sound version of the site. Rather, to avoid preventing screen readers and other relevant software from rendering the content properly.

Answer (score 1):

This is quite a broad topic but can be covered relatively easily.

What you're talking about is making use of Web Accessibility. The best way to be able to achieve eb accessibility is to make sure that your mark-up is valid and everything keeps to a certain structure that a screen reader or robot would be able to read it with ease and relay that back to a blind person.

The W3C have a full initiative towards Web Accessibility (the WAI) who are there to sort out how to verify a page is accessible for those incapable of accessing the web in the normal way (Mouse, keyboard and monitor).

They have a set of easy checks which are easy to follow and make amendments from your website to.

Read them here: http://www.w3.org/WAI/eval/preliminary

Ultimately, your best way to achieve full web accessibility is to ensure that the HTML mark-up is clean and has every last piece of meta data required, all images have alt tags and the structure to your page is easy for robots to understand and follow. HTML5 helps with this massively as you now have the usage of tags such as `<article>` and `<aside>` which are there to determine article areas and article details areas (great for blogs and news stories).

Hope this helps and if you need more information, then the W3C and WAI are your best bets.

- W3C: http://www.w3.org/
- Wai: http://www.w3.org/WAI/

Comment: If you think the topic can be covered relatively easily, I’m afraid you don’t understand much of it. The resources you recommend are OK; they are just very broad and abstract and not very digestible (should we say: not very accessible, to most people?).

Comment: In my experience of working with projects that required a great deal of web accessibility, following the guidelines given by the W3C and WAI (The two leading bodies on HTML and web accessibility) has given me the best success rate with all the screen readers. If you were to follow HTML5 guidelines and make sure that tags are used correctly and that everything is attributed correctly then there will be no problems. I guess my wording at the beginning is a bit rubbish but the rest of the answer should be sufficient enough. Especially the set of checks given by the WAI.

Answer (score 0):

There are a number of different standards people use when designing for accessibility. You generally need to include things like `alt` tags for images and links on your page, ensure your page can be viewed without JavaScript, high contrast modes, etc.

Try looking at [WAI](http://www.w3.org/WAI/) for some standards and how to get started. If accessibility is being enforced by your countries legislature, they will generally choose a standard or create one that you should adhere to.

Generally people viewing websites that need to hear the content will use a screen reader. It will go through the content and read it to the user. There are a number of readers that you can use for free and try out.

Comment: My second thought, is there some rules to follow when it comes to adapt the site for people with visual impairment? Like, can I do it MY WAY? Or do I have to follow some sort of a standard?

Comment: @Rubinen Because the issue is so broad, numerous standards have been created. If Sweden is making a law that says you need your site to be accessible, then you will need to follow the standard the government sets out. Trying to implement it your way will most likely not cover all the aspects described in Sweden's standard and therefore, your site would not be considered accessible.

Comment: Viewability without JavaScript may be interesting, but there is little blindness-related in it. And low versus high contrast does not have much difference to people who are completely blind.

Comment: @JukkaK.Korpela Some screen readers read the pages as if JavaScript is disabled. If you use JavaScript to alter content, it can cause issues with the screen reader. While high contrast doesn't help completely blind people, there are many people not completely blind that it does help.